# Add SMTP Gmail authentication to PHP Mailer contact form

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a working PHP email form that works about 10% of the time. I need to add authentication to make it work 100% of the time but I'm trying to use PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and am getting errors and can't get it to work.

My basic working script without authentication:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your message. Please check that all fields are filled in.";
        exit;
    }

    $recipient = "myaddress@gmail.co";
    $subject = "Enquiry from $name";
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
    $email_headers = "From: Enquiry <myenquiry@gmail.co>";

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} 
else {
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: As the posted answer said, you're not using phpmailer. Try using the gmail example here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't use PHPMailer in your code
to get PHPMailer by composer https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

I tried it 15 minutes ago and it works fine for me 100% of the time (I tried only ~20 times)
the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 

       $mail->IsSMTP();
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
       $mail->Port = 465;
       $mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
       $mail->Password = "ur pass";

       $mail->ChartSet = 'utf-8';
       $mail->From     = 'me';
       $mail->Subject  = "subject here";
       $mail->AddAddress( 'email@gmail.com' ); //to
       $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
       $mail->IsHTML( true );
       $mail->IsSMTP();

       $mail->send();
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's working perfectly offline but as soon as it's on my server the emails won't send - will see what I can do from here, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

From this code, it looks like you are using PHP's built-in `mail()` function, not phpmailer.  If you are using phpmailer, you should have a line that creates a new PHPMailer object, such as: `$mail = new PHPMailer;`.  See http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail for an example of how to use PHPMailer to send a message through Gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com), with authentication.